# Transforming Power and Exponential Functions

Tags: self-study, data-transformation

- Suppose two variables x and y have no linear correlation. If we transform the data by replacing each y value with its base-10 logarithm, then will x and log $y$ also have zero correlation?
- In transforming a power function, does the base $c$ for log$_c$ $y$ and for log$_c$ $x$ matter? Can any $c$ greater than 0 be used?

Comment: It's not clear what, exactly "no correlation (not necessarily linear)" encompasses. Do you intend independence or something weaker than independence? (and if so, what, exactly?)

Comment: Sorry, I mean two variables with a Pearson's r of 0.

Comment: Do the questions in the second bullet point apply only to the situation in the first bullet point or is that an entirely new question?

Comment: Two different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No -- the correlation can be non-zero.

   Here's an example in R:

   ```
   x = (0:10) + 0.003
   y = 1 + (x-mean(x))^2
   cor(x,y)
   [1] -9.892917e-18
    cor(log(x),log(y))
   [1] -0.379543
   ```

   Another example:

   ```
   x = runif(1000000)
   y = runif(1000000,0,sqrt(.25-(x-.5)^2))
   ```

   [image]

   Note that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent (and I assume positive, so you can take logs), then $\log(X)$ and $\log(Y)$ will also be independent, but in general it's not the case that you can take logs of uncorrelated variables and still have them uncorrelated.

---

2. Changing the base of the log only changes the result by a constant scaling factor. So anything that is unaffected by changing the scale will not be affected by changing the base of the logarithm.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the first answer, is this always the case? Or are there instances where transforming does not affect the correlation?

Comment: @auguste Yes, there are cases where transforming doesn't affect the correlation. For example, if the two variables are independent, it will always be the case. (This is why I was careful to ask about your intended meaning in the initial post.)